# Git Shell - Always Shows Red Asterisk

Tags: git

I have used git-sh for a while, and it used to always have the red * when there were changes to the branch.  Now it shows this * always.  See example below.

```
master!reponame *> status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
master!reponame *>
```

Any idea why?

Also checked for parent repositories

```
master!reponame *> cd ..
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
!projects *>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you initiated a repository in a parent directory inadvertently?

Comment: master!reponame *> cd ..
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
!projects *>